# How to customize code generated from Web Appbuilder for ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-web-appbuilder

I created a web application using the Web AppBuilder for ArcGIS.

However, how can I edit the code to add new features (functions)? e.g. I already added one published geoprocessing (an url) to the widgit (other panel).

However, I could not just find the corresponding code that I downloaded.

Could anyone with this experience give me some guidance?

Comment: Are you trying to figure out how to download the code for an AppBuilder app so that you can customize it more locally? Or did you already download it and you are trying to learn how to change/edit the functionality?

Comment: I am trying to learn how to change/edit the functionality. However, I found there are a bunch of files and code from Dojo which confused me a lot. Do you have some experiences on generating report with maps that extracted from the online/local database?

Comment: There's an official guide, widget development starts here: https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/guide/naming-conventions.htm